# How to move a Sprite after rotation In the indicated direction? Libgdx - Java - Android

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I have a video game in which an arrow moves towards the side where it is pointing, after rotation the arrow, example:

[image]

I need to move the sprite To the same direction in which the arrow points after it has been rotation.
A bit of code As I'm trying to do:

```
int count = 0;
@Override
protected void handleInput() {
     if(Gdx.input.justTouched()){
         // move to the direction of pointing:
         arrow.setPosition(x, y);
     }

}

public void update(float dt){

    count++;
    // rotate sprite:
    arrow.setRotation(count);

}
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Moving the sprite while rotating it, or first rotate the sprite and then move it?

Answer (score 2):

In the book "Beginning Java Game Development with LibGDX" the author makes a game that I think demonstrates the behaviour you want. The game is "Starfish Collector" from chapter 3. The player moves a turtle to collect starfish. The left and right arrow keys rotate the turtle, and the up arrow key moves the turtle forward in the direction he is currently facing.

The source code for the game can be downloaded from the author's Github account [here](https://github.com/Apress/beg-java-game-dev-w-libgdx/blob/master/978-1-4842-1501-2_Ch03_code.zip). (I don't know why he put it in a zip file.)

The relevant code looks like this:

```
@Override
public void update(float dt) {
    // process input
    turtle.setAccelerationXY(0, 0);

    if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.LEFT)) {
        turtle.rotateBy(90 * dt);
    }
    if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.RIGHT)) {
        turtle.rotateBy(-90 * dt);
    }
    if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.UP)) {
        turtle.accelerateForward(100);
    }
    // ...
```

Where `turtle` extends some custom classes that extend `Actor`.

The code for `accelerateForward` looks like this:

```
public void accelerateForward(float speed) {
    setAccelerationAS(getRotation(), speed);
}
```

And then the code for `setAccelerationAS` looks like this:

```
// set acceleration from angle and speed
public void setAccelerationAS(float angleDeg, float speed) {
    acceleration.x = speed * MathUtils.cosDeg(angleDeg);
    acceleration.y = speed * MathUtils.sinDeg(angleDeg);
}
```

Note that this last bit of code is probably exactly what user unexistential was referring to.

(I recommend this book if you're learning LibGDX and game development. It's very good.)

**See also:**

- [Beginning Java Game Development with LibGDX by Lee Stemkoski](http://www.apress.com/us/book/9781484215012)
- [Book's source code](https://github.com/apress/beg-java-game-dev-w-libgdx)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to use the sine and cosine of the rotation amount to determine the x and y components of the translation vector.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved with this page: [enter link description here](https://github.com/Igor-Lopes/LibGdx/blob/master/Splash.java#L125)

```
        float mX = 0;
float mY = 0;
int velocity = 5;
private float posAuxX = 0;
private float posAuxY = 0;
int count = 0;
public void update(float dt){
    count2++;
    flecha.setRotation(count2);
    if (count2 >= 360){
        count2 =  0;
    }
    position = new Vector2((float) Math.sin(count2) * velocity,
            (float) Math.cos(count2 * velocity));
    mX = (float) Math.cos(Math.toRadians(flecha.getRotation()));
    mY = (float) Math.sin(Math.toRadians(flecha.getRotation()));
    position.x = mX;
    position.y = mY;
    if (position.len() > 0){
        position = position.nor();
    }
    position.x = position.x * velocity;
    position.y = position.y * velocity;
    posAuxX = flecha.getX();
    posAuxY = flecha.getY();
```

}

flecha.setPosition(posAuxX, posAuxY);

Comment: You should mark your answer as correct if it fixed your problem.